# Why doesn't PowerPC's stfs instruction behave as expected?

Tags: floating-point, powerpc

PowerPC's floating point registers only support double-precision format, so loading and storing single-precision values requires conversion. The conversion from single to double on load makes sense, but the conversion from double to single for storing does some confusing things. It seems to correctly truncate numbers that are within single-precision range, as well as NaNs, infinity, and zero, but does some weird shifting for everything else instead of rounding to zero or infinity like I would expect.

Examples from PPC750 CPU. The examples which give the result I expected are listed first.

```
double-precision input    decimal approximation    single-precision output    decimal approximation

0x 400f ffff ffff ffff    3.99999999               0x 407f ffff               3.99999976
0x 7ff8 0000 0000 0000    QNaN                     0x 7fc0 0000               QNaN
0x 7ff0 0000 0000 0000    +inf                     0x 7f80 0000               +inf
0x 8000 0000 0000 0000    -0.0                     0x 8000 0000               -0.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x 8000 0000 0000 0001    -4.941e-324              0x 8080 0000               -1.175e-38
0x 00a0 0000 0000 0000    1.139e-305               0x 0500 0000               6.019e-36
0x 7fe0 1234 5678 9abc    9.028e+307               0x 7f00 91a2               1.709e+38
```

I looked at the [PowerPC Programming Environments Manual](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/MPCFPE32B.pdf)
 to see if it could shed some light on this. Section C.7 describes the steps for the conversion for "No Denormalization Required" and "Denormalization Required" cases. (Note that `||` in this notation means concatenation.)

[image: conversion steps]

Then it goes on to state:

> Note that if the value to be stored by a single-precision store
>   floating-point instruction is larger in  magnitude than the maximum
>   number representable in single format, the first case mentioned, “No 
>   Denormalization Required,” applies. The result stored  in WORD is then
>   a well-defined value but is not  numerically equal to the value in the
>   source register (that is, the result of a single-precision load 
>   floating-point from WORD does not compare equal to  the contents of
>   the original source register).

That explains why I got the results I did, but it doesn't explain how that's useful. It seems to me like it would cause horrible errors if the values are ever loaded from memory again.

Why doesn't the stfs instruction perform normal rounding? How is the result expected not to cause problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stfs` documentation says “Note that the value to be stored should be in single-precision format prior to the execution of the **stfs** instruction.” This means the contents of the register being stored should be the result of some prior instruction that produces a single-precision value, such as `fmuls` (single-precision floating-point multiply) or `frsp` (round to single-precision).

I would hazard a guess part of the reason is so that it could be fast and easy to implement—`stfs` does not have to do rounding and does not have to go to a floating-point unit to do that. It can go directly to a load-store unit which only has logic for handling simpler cases, in which truncating the bits suffices.

Comment: I think you're right about the PowerPC designers' intent. But would it really be that much slower to check the exponent and store +/- zero or +/- infinity where necessary? It must already be checking the exponent in order to find numbers in the single-precision denormal range, so it seems like a trivial amount of additional logic could cover numbers outside the single-precision range.